# In Git, what is the difference between long and short hashes?

Tags: git, hash

Here is the long Git hash:

commit c26cf8af130955c5c67cfea96f9532680b963628

Merge: 8654907 37c2a4f

Author: nicolas

Date:   Wed Apr 26 13:28:22 2017 -0400

Here is the short one:

[image]

Comment: short hash shows the first 7 characters of hash. Short hash of c26cf8af130955c5c67cfea96f9532680b963628 is c26cf8a in second row. [See docu](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection): "Git is smart enough to figure out what commit you meant to type if you provide the first few characters, as long as your partial SHA-1 is at least four characters long and unambiguous"

Comment: No, the long hash is not a reference. It is the *content hash* of the actual content of the object it stands for (a commit in this case). Everything in git has hashes (for example, trees, files, tags etc.), not only hashes. References (refs) are a different thing altogether, they are a pair of (name,hash) which gives us a nice human-compatible way to work with them.

Answer (score 68):

To elaborate a bit more about why the short hash is useful, and why you often don't need the long hash, it has to do with how Git stores things.

`c26cf8af130955c5c67cfea96f9532680b963628` will be stored in one of two places. It could be in the file `.git/objects/c2/6cf8af130955c5c67cfea96f9532680b963628`. Note that the first two characters, `c2`, make up a directory and the rest is the filename. Since many filesystems don't perform well when there's too many files in one directory, this prevents any one directory from having too many files in it and keeps this little directory database efficient.

With just the short hash, `c26cf8a`, git can do the equivalent of `.git/objects/c2/6cf8a*` and that's likely to be a single file. Since the objects are subdivided into subdirectories, there's not too many filenames to look through to check if there's more than one match.

`c26cf8a` alone contains enough possibilities, 16^7 or 2^28 or 268,435,456 that it's very unlikely another commit will share that prefix.

Basically, Git uses the filesystem itself as a simple key/value store, and it can look up partial keys without having to scan the whole list of keys.

---

That's one way to store objects. More and more, Git stores its objects in [packfiles](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles). It's a *very* efficient way to store just the changes between files. From time to time, your Git repository will examine what's in `.git/objects` and store just the differences in `.git/objects/pack/pack-<checksum>`.

That's a binary format, I'm not going to get into it here, and I don't understand it myself anyway. :)

Comment: In my environment, each repo seems to determine the length of the short sha differently. On one of the repos I work on it's 11. This is from doing the `git rev-parse --short HEAD`. Is there some explanation somewhere how it computes the length? is it based on the total number of commits in the repo?

Comment: Oh, it is based on the number of objects: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreabbrev

Comment: @nroose I didn't know that the short SHA length changed dynamically. That does make sense, thank you.

Answer (score 15):

A short hash is just the first 7 characters of your full hash.

Right below the circled commit in your screenshot, you can see a commit labeled `c26cf8a`. This should be the commit `c26cf8af130955c5c67cfea96f9532680b963628` you were looking for.

Comment: Default length of abbreviated commit hash varies. It seems, it depends on history length. I know cases 7, 8, 9 bytes. Use [--abbrev](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---abbrevltngt) parameter to set this length strongly

Answer (score 11):

The short hash shows the first seven characters of the hash. The short hash of c26cf8af130955c5c67cfea96f9532680b963628 is c26cf8a in the second row. See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection):

> Git is smart enough to figure out what commit you meant to type if you provide the first few characters, as long as your partial SHA-1 is at least four characters long and unambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

The short hash is just a shorter version of the original (long) hash. The original Git hash is 40 bytes long while short is only 8 bytes long. However, it becomes difficult to manage it (in terms of using typing or displaying), and that's why the short version is used.

This approach is used in almost all the projects where a hash is either for *integrity* (package distribution), *versioning* (Git and SVN) or *layered* architecture (Docker).

Comment: Isn't short actually 7 nibbles  long resp 28 bits? and long 160 bits?