# Azure Devops: Shorten $(SourceBranchName) when used within pipeline name directive

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our yml-definition files for an Azure-pipeline start with

`name: $(Build.DefinitionName)_$(SourceBranchName)_$(rev:rrrrr)`

With that, we get very long build names that have negative consequences for display in build result pages. Therefore we would like to shorten the `$(SourceBranchName)` to the e.g. first 20 characters.

Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

> we would like to shorten the $(SourceBranchName) to the e.g. first 20 characters.

You could try to use `command line\powershell` script to split long string into short.

```
steps:
- script: |
   echo $(Build.SourceBranchName)
   
   set  TestVar=$(Build.SourceBranchName)
   
   set MyCustomVar= %TestVar:~0,20%
   
   echo %MyCustomVar%
   
   echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=CustomVar]%MyCustomVar%
   
  displayName: 'Get the first 20 character versions of Build.SourceBranchName'
```

Then we could get the short string of the `SourceBranchName`.

Generally, `SourceBranchName` is different from `SourceVersion`, and it is generally not a very long string. If your `SourceBranchName` is indeed a very long string, then the above method will help you.

You could check [my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973612/is-there-a-short-7-digit-version-of-sourceversion-in-azure-devops/56986108#56986108) for some more details.

**Note:** If you want to shorten your build names, we need update the build number for current build through Logging Command (e.g. `Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]buildnumber"`)：

```
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(Build.DefinitionName).$(CustomVar).$(rev:rrrrr)"
```

But the `$(rev:rrrrr)` could not be available in the task, so we have to include `$(rev:rrrrr)` in default build number format (Options), for example: `$(date:yyyyMMdd)-$(rev:rrrrr)`. And Get current build number from pre-defined variable (`Build.BuildNumber/BUILD_BUILDNUMBER`), then we parse the value of `$(rev:rrrrr)`.

Comment: I have a nicely encapsulated task called Transform Variable with a substring option: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks. There's also a Regex Search & Replace option.