# How to create a file in during Azure Pipeline that includes build.* variables

Tags: .net, azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to create the following json structure and include it with my .NET application using Azure Pipelines and it is not clear to me how to do so.

```
{
"buildNumber":"$(Build.BuildNumber)",
"buildId":"$(Build.BuildId)",
"branchName":"$(Build.SourceBranchName)",
"commitHash":"$(Build.SourceVersion)"
}
```

I've tried simply doing a command line to echo the information into a file but I'm not sure of the path necessary to have it picked up by the publish step.

Right now I am experimenting with a powershell task:

```
    - task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.

      new-item -itemtype file -path $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyFirstExperiment -name "buildinfo.json" -force -value '{
      \"buildNumber\":\"$(Build.BuildNumber)\",
      \"buildId\":\"$(Build.BuildId)\",
      \"branchName\":\"$(Build.SourceBranchName)\",
      \"commitHash\":\"$(Build.SourceVersion)\"
      }'
```

I see output during the task that the file is created but I must still be missing something obvious because it is not showing up in the build / publish later in the pipeline.

What should I be checking?

I strongly suspect that I am missing something very obvious because there is not a lot of results doing google searches for 'azure pipeline create file'

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To get the **short git commit hash** of `$(Build.SourceVersion)` look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62469078/789423). It saves the short hash (as shown in the commit history) to variable `$(short_hash)`, which you can include to your file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you're using `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`, which is the location where your source code files are downloaded. Use `$(Build.StagingDirectory)` instead, this is where any artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination.

Reference: [Build variables (DevOps Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services)

If permitted by your org, you can also consider using an extension from the Visual Studio Marketplace, like [File Creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eliostruyf.build-task). This is a task that can be added as a step to your pipeline to create a file during a build or release process.

Comment: I fixed that (THANK YOU!) and now I have the file showing up at the end along with the zip of the publishing output. Is there any way that I can get the file into the zip? I had thought that if I added it before the build step it would get copied but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Happy to help! Indeed, you could [copy the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to the destination and then [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) it as part of the build artifacts.

Comment: MSBuild is a complicated beast. If you could generate the file as part of the build process, you could then add it to your outputs (either by creating an item `<Content Include="Path\to\file" CopyToOutputDirectory='PreserveNewest' />`, or even using `<ContentWithTargetPath Include="..." CopyToOutputDirecory="PreserveNewest" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" TargetPath="some\other\path\in\bin\Release" />`. Look through Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets. There's a LOT to be learned!