# How do I change the author and author email for multiple commits?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-filter-branch, git-cherry-pick, git-filter-repo

This was a problem I wanted to solve. When I searched up this question, I saw answers using `git filter-branch` and `git filter-repo`.

I can say with 100% confidence that `git filter-branch` is too slow and I don't like that it can change the same commit in multiple branches. Not a useful method.

Next is `git filter-repo`. It seems like a good solution but I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which doesn't seem to be supported. I would need to spend a little time to update to 22.04 LTS. So only useful on supported distros and versions.

Now here is my answer:

```
initialCommit=$(git log original-branch --format=format:"%h" | tail -1)
readarray -t commitsArray < <(git log original-branch --author="Original Author <originalauthor@email.com>" --format=format:"%h")
startCommitIndex=$(("${#commitsArray[@]}"-1))

git checkout -b new-branch "$initialCommit"
if [[ "$initialCommit" == "${commitsArray[$startCommitIndex]}" ]]; then
    git commit --amend --author "New Author <newauthor@email.com>"
    startCommitIndex=$(($startCommitIndex - 1))
fi
for (( commitIndex=$startCommitIndex; commitIndex >= 0; commitIndex-- )); do
    git cherry-pick "${commitsArray[$commitIndex]}"
    git commit --amend --author "New Author <newauthor@email.com>"
done
```

We learned that `git commit --amend --author "New Author <newauthor@email.com>"` [modifies the latest commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/how-to-change-the-commit-author-for-a-single-commit/43231587#43231587), also known as the HEAD commit (`git log -1 --format=format:"%h"`).

Regarding `--format=format:"%h"`, we can retrieve a commit's hash in two ways:

1. `--format=format:"%H"`: A long hash. Retrieves the full hash of the commit (40 characters long).
2. `--format=format:"%h"`: A shortened version of the hash that uses the first 7 to 9 characters ([length varies depending on history length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665836/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-long-and-short-hashes#comment117653573_43666045)). Git is smart enough to figure out what commit is meant with this hash.

The `git cherry-pick` command allows you to pick a commit's hash from any branch and drop the contents of that commit into another branch. This creates a new commit hash in the branch with those contents, which becomes a HEAD commit.

`git checkout -b new-branch "$initialCommit"` creates a new branch with `$initialCommit` becoming the HEAD commit.

In this way, we are able to change the author and author email for multiple commits (that we found with `readarray -t commitsArray < <(git log original-branch --author="Original Author <originalauthor@email.com>" --format=format:"%h")`).

Afterwards, we could choose to remove our original branch (`git branch -D original-branch`) and rename our new branch (`git branch -m new-branch original-branch`). Then if satisfied later decide to push our changes to GitHub, GitLab, or wherever your git project is stored in remotely. Done!

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 should be good. You can read this : [How do you install git-filter-repo?](https://superuser.com/a/1589985/659315)

Comment: Not a bad solution @AsifKamranMalick. But the answer I propose solves this problem using only built-in git commands. It doesn't require python (version 3) like git-filter-repo does. Personally, I find this solution uses less time to do what I need it to do. I do have python 3 but there is a chance some machines may not have python 3. So basically this solution does not depend on python. Only Git (and basic bash syntax).

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: What does mean "git filter-branch can change a commit in multiple branches"? filter-branch will rewrite all commit ranges given on the commandline plus refs

Comment: @knittl This is the scenario: You have a git repository with multiple branches. Some branches are feature branches, checked out from the main branch. If you use "git log" to look at the commit hashes across multiple branches, I believe some of these commits share the same exact hash.

So, when I used "git filter-branch", I saw it rewrote the same commit across multiple branches which I thought was dangerous!

Comment: @knittl The question of this post is the title: How do I change the author and author name for multiple commits?

I saw multiple solutions and thought there should be a better way to solve it. I have no problems with some of them, like git-filter-repo if it works for you, however maybe my solution is more intuitive. It solves a git problem in git while git-filter-repo solves a git problem in python.

Comment: @Dennis your premise is wrong. "commits on different branches share the same exact hash". That's not correct. Commits do not "share hashes". It's only a single commit. A branch is not "a thing" in Git. A branch points to a single commit and this commit points to its parent, which points to its parent(s), and so on. If you run filter-branch on all branches/refs, then a new commit will be created. The refs/branches will be updated to include this new commit as their ancestor. So I'm still not sure what your question is, because a commit only exists once; therefore you can only rewrite it once :)